# How to do ng-repeat on $firebaseArray output with multiple levels?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `$firebaseArray` for collecting the data from Firebase. Output is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "BankAccount": {
      "AccountHolder": "Tom Antony",
      "AccountNumber": "56767887"
    },    
    "Info": {
      "BillingAddress": {
        "City": "XYZ",
        "State": "ABC"
      },
      "FullName": "Tom Antony",
      "PhoneNumber": "634762347"
    },
    "$id": "dGUZX5SWi7aP0SNYLYqEiMdCYAS2",
    "$priority": null
  },

  {
    "Campaigns": {      
        "Settings": {
          "Active": true
        }
      }
    },
    "Info": {
      "BillingAddress": {
        "City": "ABC",
        "State": "DFG"
      },
      "FullName": "Mario",
      "PhoneNumber": "634762347"
    },
    "$id": "tBqGZ7g6VwNYOWoVy7C1FHKZKFS2",
    "$priority": null
  }
]
```

My js is as follows:

```
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Users');        
$scope.users = $firebaseArray(rootRef);
```

Each Array element will have different type of objects, but each will have a similar object called **Info**, which contains a field for **FullName** I need to apply ng-repeat on this FullName. My implementation is as shown below:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users.Info">
    <p ng-bind="user.FullName"></p>
</div>
```

But its not working. What are the mistakes I made here?

Comment: Are you referring to Controller as AdminCtrl  if so I would say that I've never seen this way of reaching variables through controller .And please share some console logs explaining the errors you see.

Comment: @katmanco Thanks. that was actually unintentional. But there were no Errors on console logs.

Comment: @katmanco My problem still exists. Can you pls help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate on the wrong property.  You have two objects (`user`) which *each* have an `Info` property that you want the `FullName` from.  You do not have two `Info` objects.  Therefore, you should be iterating over the `users`, not iterating over `users.Info`.

Try this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <p ng-bind="user.Info.FullName"></p>
</div>
```

Also, your object you pasted here wasn't valid JSON, you had an extra `}`.

Full Working example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ryfjhO0c3egHfKnaL9SQ?p=preview